# Plotting transect line with equally spaced points and get the coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, line, distance, vector-layer, point-creation

In QGIS I am trying to plot a transect line. For this I would like to place points every 500m along a line and get the coordinates of each point, but have not managed to achieve this unfortunately.

Is there a method to do this? Alternatively, dividing a line into equal parts not specified by distance but by a number of intervals along a line would also work.

Answer (score 5):

1. Provided you have a line, you can use the ["Points along geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) tool:

   [image]
2. As for the coordinates, you can use the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator): `$x` for X and `$y` for Y coordinates, you need to calculate twice and put the results in 2 different fields.

   [image]

   [image]